# Docker compose breaks ssh connection

Tags: docker, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run a few docker containers on GCP VMs. As of today, when I run a docker-compose, my ssh connection breaks. This was not happening as of this morning. The only thing that changed was I did a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

An example of a docker-compose file that breaks the connection:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - "27017"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

I'm on Ubuntu `5.13.0-1030-gcp #36~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 3 15:33:42 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

docker-compose version 1.25.0

Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

and I'm using BuildKit for my Docker and docker-compose builds.

I'm not sure how to debug this issue, any suggestions would be appreciated. Will update the post with more info if needed.

Comment: Hey, I had the same problem until this morning. Now, I noticed a kernel update and now everything works smoothly! Just update the kernel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your dmesg to see if the kernel crashed.
Probably related to https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg482001.html

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely what I'm experiencing. I'm glad to know it wasn't something I messed up.

Answer (score 1):

in our case it was an internal ip address space exhaustion
because docker switches afterwards to the 192.168.*.* network

and blocks external traffic

to fix - shutdown all docker containers
purge all docker networks
add or append to docker daemon.json

e.g. vi /etc/docker/daemon.json for 512 networks

```
{
    "default-address-pools":[
        {"base":"172.20.0.0/16","size":24},
        {"base":"172.21.0.0/16","size":24}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Do not update your kernel,new kernel will influence docker process

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).